# Can the verb “tend” be followed by a bare infinitive (“tend be” v.s. “tend to be”)?

Tags: bare-infinitive

I thought *tend* (used to imply “regularly or frequently behaving in a particular way or having a certain characteristic – Oxford’s def; 1.1) always has to be used with the [to-infinitive](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/infin2.htm) form of verbs.

Today, however, I encountered this example:

> Most meta-analyses show that, with some exceptions, well-established
>   psychotherapies **tend be** approximately equivalent in efﬁcacy (Wampold,
>   Mondin, Moody, Stich, Benson, & Ahn, 1997).

And while I couldn’t find anything regarding *tend* in regards to these two forms (with or without “be”), [searching .edu domains precisely for "tend be"](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=site%3aedu%20%22tend%20be%22) returns some 12,000 results. E.g.:

> Fungal-like protists and the Chytridiomycota **tend be** aseptate, except to delimit reproductive or specialized cells (such as sporangia and gametangia).
>
> ---
>
> The disadvantages of physical sunscreens is that they **tend be** thicker and look a little white on the skin.
>
> ---
>
> [The book] reveals that readers [...] **tend be** more open to diversity; politically tolerant; less authoritarian; less likely to support the use of deadly force or torture; more politically active; and are more likely to have a negative view of the Bush administration.
>
> ---
>
> It has long been appreciated that genes that perform core functions **tend be** more conserved in amino acid sequence over long evolutionary time periods.

So, is it ok to write “tends be” instead of “tends to be”?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: I found that Google has plenty of book mentions of this as well https://www.google.com/search?q="tend+be"&tbm=bks - it'd be hard to think this is just a bunch of typos...unless people tend be careless with their writing? ;)

Comment: This reminds me of the usage "leave be". A common form of "leave it alone".

Comment: Only Richard Bach is allowed to do that  :)

Comment: Seriously, they are simply typos - it's that simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [OED provides for no such usage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tend). Adapting the examples:

1) Tend can be used with *to/towards*.

> Walter tended to run.

or

> Walter tended towards corpulence.

or

> ... tends towards infinity.

2) Tend can be used with an adverbial:

> fire is hot and tends upwards

---

No dictionary seems to provide for a usage like:

> ... tend be ...

---

**Verdict**: typo or perhaps a written form of informal/idiomatic speech. (The "tend be" form sounds slightly familiar to my ear, like I've heard people saying it; particularly in the form "*they do tend be ...*".)

Comment: I can't think of any raising verbs off-hand that catenate with a bare infinitive.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to badroit's excellent answer:

[Tend be is unplottable on an NGRAM.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tend+be%2C+tend+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctend%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0)

If you are unfamiliar with its use, an [NGRAM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) is a search for a word form or string within an entire corpus of literature which can compare its relative prevalence (statistical probability of occurrence).  When asking a question of this type, plotting an NGRAM can often help answer your question.

[Google Books has an excellent NGRAM viewer.](https://books.google.com/ngrams)  It readily allows you to assess the prevalence of words and phrases within all of Google Books's considerable corpus!

As Edwin Ashworth points out, it is not a perfect tool.  Just one more in the arsenal.

Comment: Not even a single false positive for say 'Should the patients you tend be largely over 80, avoid suggesting 10-mile hikes as therapy'?

Comment: Better as a comment?

Comment: @bib It was too long.  I wasn't looking for rep.  Just to inform the OP.  (That's why I credited badroit in my answer.)  I'll turn it Community Wiki if you think it proper.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was surprised by that, too!

Comment: Just sounding the usual warning note about Ngrams being like fire – very useful if used with great care, but dangerous if misused.

Comment: @bib It is Community Wiki now.  I will not receive any rep from the answer.

Comment: _Tend to be_ would come out ['tɛnɾəbi], and if that unstressed syllable in the middle syncopates -- which happens in fast speech, and speech is pretty fast with CYA verbs like _tend_ -- you get the oral equivalent of _tend be_. The print version may have been dictated and transcribed, who knows? But I think @Edwin's right about [Raising verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: Excellent and informative answer, thanks for posting it.

Comment: This is useful information, but I'd be happier if it were incorporated into badroit's answer since this should really be a comment.